# Difference of Pythagorean triples

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I don't know how to find solutions to this problem other than trial and error. I appreciate all responses.

> 1. Are there Pythagorean triples whose difference also yields a perfect square?
>
> $(a,b,c)$ such that $(a^2+b^2=c^2) \land (b \gt a) \land$ $(b^2−a^2=d^2), a,b,c,d\in \Bbb N$
>
> 2. Is there also a solution where $a^2$ or $b^2$ is a perfect squares of a prime, and also $c^2$ and $d^2$ are perfect squares of a prime? (three out of four values)

Thanks!

Comment: rewording may help you to focus the search, for the first question, you are looking for Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ / ($a^2+b^2=c^2) \land (b \gt a)$ (ordered) and at the same time $b^2-a^2=d^2$, $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb N$

Comment: Thanks, I think I simplified it enough now.

Comment: done, now the text is complete I think, good luck! Some months ago I did also a question regarding squares and primes, it is not exactly related with your question, but if you are interested in this kind of topics, you can get insights about where to focus in your research. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218279/prove-about-prime-numbers-obtained-from-certain-sums-of-squares-of-an-integer-n

Comment: I'm looking at the list of Pythagorean triples and it appears that they must contain at least one even number, so all four values cannot have perfect squares whose factors are prime.

Comment: It's been known since antiquity at all Pythagorean triples include either one or three even numbers,

Comment: Thank you @MYUSERNAMEISALIE
It's updated now.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43519/squares-in-arithmetic-progression

Comment: Have a look also at this wonderful page: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath044/kmath044.htm   The first problem implies that $d^2,d^2+a^2,d^2+2a^2$ is a 3AP.

Comment: Also, http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/3squarearithprog.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that $(d^2,d^2+a^2,d^2+2a^2)=(d^2,b^2,c^2)$.

The answer to your first question is then in the first lines of [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_right_triangle_theorem).

> **Fermat's right triangle theorem**: If three square numbers form an arithmetic progression, then the gap between consecutive numbers in the progression cannot itself be square.

Fermat's proof (through infinite descent) can be found on the same page.

Equivalent results are that $1$ is not a [congruent number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_number), or that the only rational points on the elliptic curve $$y^2 = x(x-1)(x+1)$$ are the trivial ones. Some references:

- http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath044/kmath044.htm
- http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/3squarearithprog.pdf
- [Squares in arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43519/squares-in-arithmetic-progression).

Comment: What about triples that are not arithmetic progressions?

Comment: @lurker: what does your question mean? Generic triples of squares? Yes, they exist. There are also triples of squares in AP, but with common difference that is not a square, like $1,25,49$, for instance.

Comment: The theorem states that if they form an arithmetic progression then the gap cannot be square, so I assume this applies to my question in that all Pythagorean triples that are also arithmetic progression cannot have difference that is a perfect square. I wanted to know if this also applies in all instances where it is not an arithmetic progression.

Comment: @lurker: so, if I understood correctly, you are asking if there is an infinite number of triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $a^2+b^2$ is a square and $b^2+c^2$ is a square. In such a case, the answer is clearly affirmative, by considering the general form of a primitive pythagorean triple. If we take $a=(4u^2-v^2),b=(4uv),c=2(u^2-v^2)$, then $a^2+b^2=(4u^2+v^2)^2$ and $b^2+c^2=(2u^2-2v^2)^2$ as wanted.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for your elegant response. What are the three smallest numbers that would be an example of this?

Comment: @lurker: $(15,8,6)$ is the triple generated by $(u,v)=(2,1)$ ($15^2+8^2=17^2$ and $8^2+6^2=10^2$). I don't know if it is the smallest one, but since its elements are quite small, one may check smaller cases by hand.

Comment: Wait... I may have misread your interpretation, I'm talking about where a > b and $ a^2 + b^2 $ is a square, and $ a^2 - b^2 $ is also a square.

Comment: @iadvd was correct in the questions initial comment.

Comment: @lurker: if both $a^2+b^2$ and $a^2-b^2$ are squares, then $a^2-b^2,a^2,a^2+b^2$ is a 3AP of squares having a square as common difference. That is discussed above.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks